# Stack overflow with a loop c#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I am currently having problems with this loop. It becomes an infinite loop and i get a stack overflow error. This is for a interest rate trade swap application. i is the length of the trade and l is the increasing index.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int outp = 0;
            int i = int.Parse(tradeLength.Text);
            string month = "January";
            for (int l = 1; l <= i; l++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I iterated " + l + " Amount of times");
                if (l == 1)
                {
                    month = "January";
                }
                if (l == 2)
                {
                    month = "February";
                }
                if (l == 3)
                {
                    month = "March";
                }
                if (l == 4)
                {
                    month = "Aprll";
                }
                if (l == 5)
                {
                    month = "May";
                }
                if (l == 6)
                {
                    month = "June";
                }
                if (l == 7)
                {
                    month = "July";
                }
                if (l == 8)
                {
                    month = "August";
                }
                if (l == 9)
                {
                    month = "September";
                }
                if (l == 10)
                {
                    month = "October";
                }
                if (l == 11)
                {
                    month = "November";
                }
                if (l == 12)
                {
                    month = "December";
                }
                else
                {
                    month = "Null";
                    l = 1;
                }
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can get a month's name by using `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(index)`

Comment: The code is incomplete and the cause of your problem is the last else case.

Comment: Your last section of code is saying "If `l` isn't 12, set it to 1"

Comment: Actual problem aside, you should consider learning to use `switch() {}` instead of this `if`mayhem.

Comment: **Thanks** rly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the final `else`:

```
    if (l == 12) {
      month = "December";
    }
    else { // <- if l != 12 (e.g. l == 1) restart the loop 
      month = "Null";
      l = 1;
    }
```

you want `else if`:

```
    if (l == 1)
    {
        month = "January";
    }
    else if (l == 2) 
    {
        ... 
    }
    ...
    else if (l == 12) 
    {
        ... 
    }
    else {
      month = "Null";
      l = 1;
    }
```

**Edit:** Another problem (see *FKEinternet's* comment) is a *user input*: if `i` is greater than `12` `l` never reaches it. You have to either validate the user input:

```
    int i = int.Parse(tradeLength.Text);

    if (i > 12)
      i = 12;    // or ask for other value
```

or use *modular* arithmetics:

```
    for (int index = 1; index <= i; index++) {
      int l = index % 12 + 1;

      if (l == 1)
      {
         month = "January";
      }
      else if (l == 2)
        ...
      else if (l == 12)
        ...
      else  
      {
        month = "Null";
        l = 1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: If this `int i = int.Parse(tradeLength.Text);` evaluates to something greater than 12, you are still going to have an infinite loop with this answer because `l` will never get to `i`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good idea to set the loop variable inside the loop. Like @stuartd pointed out, in your else line you set the loop variable to 1 and causing the loop to start all over again. Remove the `l=1` line in your else block.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to go to next year when i > 12. The way your code is made, when this happens, you get to loop forever, because "l" never reaches a number bigger than 12, it becomes 1 when it hits 13 and starts over.

To fix this, instead of

```
if (l == 1)
```

you want to use

```
if ((l % 12) == 1)
```

so your entire loop would be like this:

```
 for (int l = 1; l <= i; l++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I iterated " + l + " Amount of times");
            if ((l % 12) == 1)
            {
                month = "January";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 2)
            {
                month = "February";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 3)
            {
                month = "March";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 4)
            {
                month = "Aprll";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 5)
            {
                month = "May";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 6)
            {
                month = "June";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 7)
            {
                month = "July";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 8)
            {
                month = "August";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 9)
            {
                month = "September";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 10)
            {
                month = "October";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 11)
            {
                month = "November";
            }
            if ((l % 12) == 0)
            {
                month = "December";
            }
       {
```

PS = this is really not the right way to do this, I'm just using your own code and making the least amount of mods for it to work as intented. Good luck!